# Is there a way of displaying html text on the picture in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">gdshdhfdhfdhfd</div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><img src="http://image.com/img.png" alt="cat"></div>
  </div>
<h4>header.</h4>
<p>hey there</p>
<div class="paddown">
<a class="btn btn-default" name="close" id="close" >Close</a>
</div>
</div>
```

And I would like to add any text (e.g. `<span id="txt">lorem ipsum</span>`)on the picture, let's say around 30-40px from the bottom, so it's visible in front of the cat's picture. Is it possible in bootstrap without using absolute positioning?

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2wujw71x/3/

Comment: Why don't you want to use absolute position?

Comment: Because I'm afraid what happens when user resize the page - will the text be always at the same place of the image then? Can you show me some fiddle example of it?

Comment: You can approximate with relative unites like `%` and `em` values, i.e. `top: 60%;`. Updated [makshh fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wujw71x/7/).

Comment: @hungerstar From all the answers provided here, your fits me the most, please submit it as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea to this approach is to wrap the image in a containing element that will take on the size of the image itself. You also include the overlay element inside the wrapper element.

Apply `position: relative;` to the wrapper element and apply `position: absolute;` to the overlay element. The relative positioning on the wrapper element prevents the absolutely positioned element from being positioned outside of the wrapper element which happens to be the same size as our image. We now have a *"viewport"* for the overlay element that is the same size as the image and positioned over the image.

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p>
                Lorem Ipsum
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <span class="overlay-wrapper">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://maxcdn.thedesigninspiration.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Just-A-Cat-Playing-The-Violin-l.jpg" alt="Cat"/>
                <div class="text-overlay">
                    Caption
                </div>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.overlay-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.text-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    background: rgba( 0, 0, 0, .5 );
    top: 75%;
    left: 10%;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
@media( min-width: 300px ) {
    .text-overlay {
        padding: 1em 0;
        top: 65%;
    }
}
@media( min-width: 550px ) {
    .text-overlay {
        padding: 2em 0;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o2cjkyow/

I've included some media queries in my example so you can see a demonstration on how to adjust various properties at various viewport sizes for fine-tuning.

Here's my [JSFiddle from the comments](http://jsfiddle.net/2wujw71x/7/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `img-thumbnail` class as a base with some minor adjustments, then set your text overlay rules in another class.

See working example in Snippet at Full Page.

```css
html,
body {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.img-thumbnail.overlay {
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.img-thumbnail.overlay .caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px 0 15px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.img-thumbnail.overlay .caption2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px 0 15px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="img-thumbnail overlay">
        <img src="http://maxcdn.thedesigninspiration.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Just-A-Cat-Playing-The-Violin-l.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="img-thumbnail overlay">
        <img src="http://maxcdn.thedesigninspiration.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Just-A-Cat-Playing-The-Violin-l.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="caption2">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using relative positioning instead of absolute, that way your position is always relative to the image and its container.

```
.my-floating-text{
    position: relative;
    top: 110px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

And in your html:

```
<div class="text-center">
                             <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6"><div class="my-floating-text">gdshdhfdhfdhfd</div><img src="http://maxcdn.thedesigninspiration.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Just-A-Cat-Playing-The-Violin-l.jpg" alt="cat" />
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                                <h4>header.</h4>
                                <p>hey there</p>
                                <div class="paddown">

                                    <a class="btn btn-default" name="close" id="close" >Close</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2wujw71x/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `position:absolute;`

**HTML:**

```
<div class="text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 aclass">
             <div class="auto">
                  gdshdhfdhfdhfd
             </div>
         </div>
     <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="http://maxcdn.thedesigninspiration.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Just-A-Cat-Playing-The-Violin-l.jpg" alt="cat"></div>
     </div>
    <h4>header.</h4>
    <p>hey there</p>
        <div class="paddown">
           <a class="btn btn-default" name="close" id="close" >Close</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.aclass {
   position: absolute; 
   left: 50%;
}
.auto {
    position:relative;
    top:50px; /*position to top*/
    left:-50%;
    z-index:9999;
    color:#fff;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2wujw71x/8/)

The text always is center! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just want to post an alternative approach, with figure and figcaption. The two elements aren't neccessary, but they do make it nice and semantic. The solution itself still exists in CSS. Using padding and an absolute bottom allows the container to scale with multiple lines of text.

**HTML**

```
<figure>
    <img src="http://maxcdn.thedesigninspiration.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Just-A-Cat-Playing-The-Violin-l.jpg" alt="cat">
    <figcaption>This is cat, playing violin</figcaption>
</figure>
```

**CSS**

```
figure {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

figcaption {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    bottom: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2wujw71x/10/